# Read the messages using pub/sub and load it into Datastax on Google Cloud

Tags: cassandra, google-cloud-platform, datastax-enterprise, google-cloud-pubsub

I have deployed a 9-node `Datastax` Cluster on Google cloud.

Now I've been given a requirement to read the data from QUEUE's and load into `Datastax` on google cloud( Continues Streaming).

I know pub/sub can read the data from QUEUE but not sure whether it can directly load into `Datastax`.

Is it possible for pub/sub to load the data into `Datastax` on Google cloud ?

I am new to pub/sub so not sure where to start or how to start.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You probably need custom code to do this. You'd have a Consumer to get messages from the topic you're interesting in, and then you'd have custom code to convert those messages and load them onto Datastax. I'm assuming that Datastax has an API for this.